# I want to use virtualenv of my choice of python3 like python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv

I want to create virtualenv in my docker file which use python3.6 but I don't know from where python3.4 version is come even that version is not my default version of python3 in ubuntu and I never install that in my PC

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

#RUN export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/bin/python3.6"
#ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTONPATH}:/usr/bin/python3.6"
#RUN update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6

RUN apt-get install python3
RUN python3 --version

## creating and activating env for python3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install && apt-get upgrade

#RUN export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/bin/python3.6/"
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
#
RUN python3 -m virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 /opt/venv
RUN . /opt/venv/bin/activate
```

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
#MAINTAINER dev@aee.net

#RUN export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/bin/python3.6"
#ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTONPATH}:/usr/bin/python3.6"
#RUN update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6

RUN apt-get install python3
RUN python3 --version

## creating and activating env for python3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install && apt-get upgrade

#RUN export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/bin/python3.6/"
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
#
RUN python3 -m virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 /opt/venv
RUN . /opt/venv/bin/activate
```

I want python3.6 in this virtualenv but I found python3.4

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/865569, https://gist.github.com/monkut/c4c07059444fd06f3f8661e13ccac619

Answer (score 1):

So you can install python3.6 on your docker image multiple variants to do that. Some examples [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-python-3-6-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-17-04).

But I would recommend to use one of [python docker images](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/python/). So for example if you want to have `python3.6` on your image Dockerfile should look like that:

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
RUN python3 -m virtualenv --python=$(which python3.6) /opt/venv
RUN . /opt/venv/bin/activate
```

If you indeed need Ubuntu(trusty) and other distributions (in this example Debian-stretch) are not good you can take a look at those image setups [on github](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.6/stretch/Dockerfile).